# Is possible that browser p2p with non-browser(not client-server,not relay)

Tags: sockets, browser, embedded, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm trying to find the solution that make the browser(windows) which behind NAT can p2p with the embedded linux device which behind another NAT without configure router,I have surveyed and tried fellowing methods but all cannot work:

**1.UDP hole punching**:

> a.browser cannot send UDP packet(chrome.socket seems could)
>   b.browser cannot bind port

**2.TCP hole punching**

> a.browser cannot bind port,hard to do

**3.WebRTC(studying)**

> I want to cross-compilie to my embedded linux device,try to use **RTCPeerconnection** or **RTCDataChannel** two WebRTC API to p2p with browser,I'm not sure does it can work

**4.RTP stream(haven't tried yet)**

> because I want to get video live stream from device,I saw video stream can transfer by RTP before,but RTP base on UDP,I'm not sure dose it work

I also searched some similar case like [case1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596169/web-application-nat-traversal) and [case2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447215/http-tcp-connection-to-web-server-behind-nat),but I still don't know how to do ,is possible works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is WebRTC.

WebRTC does this without any extra work (it is it's strength). This is done with ICE which is using STUN to discover external address (The STUN server itself will not relay anything. It is just a simple ping-pong protocol used as a standard for NAT handling).

However with this you can achieve only around 80-90% success bypassing NAT's (if we look at global statistics). For the rest you will need a TURN server and configure it to be used by your WebRTC client to handle the situations when UDP routing between 2 endpoints behind NAT can't work otherwise).

Comment: thank you, but it is difficult to do,I have tried several days,I think I still need more time to study..